# what is the meaning of "game" in this context?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

> A - Awesome music. We'll improve it. You game?
>
> B - I'm game.

I have no idea what ***"game"*** means here.

Comment: *[game](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/game_3)* — "ready and willing to do something new, difficult or dangerous" (OALD)

Answer (score 3):

The *OED* explains that the meaning comes from ***game***-cock, a spirited fighting bird.  So someone who is **game** has the initiative and spirit to do something.  A slang equivalent for "Are you game?" is "Are you up for it?"

Comment: I'd say *game* is an extremely dated usage today. Interestingly, there's also [a game leg](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+game+leg%22). I think that's a totally unrelated word that just happens to sound the same (to some people - personally  I always pronounce that one as ***gammy***). It's certainly a very different *meaning* (though I suppose if someone with a game leg stoically stirs themselves into action, they could be described as game).

Comment: The two uses of game come from different roots. [link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=game)